# What is the expected size of a single Mapbox Vector Tile in Pixels?

Tags: mapbox

I've been looking for a straightforward answer to this question but can't seem to find one.

The Mapbox Vector Tile Specification states implies that vector tile coordinates are unitless -- [they're just in "vector tile grid coordinates" broadly defined by the "extent" -- often 4096](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification/#encoding-geometry).

On the other hand, the Mapbox Style Specification says that properties like `line-width` [are in units of **pixels**](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-line-line-width). For instance, at zoom level 20 a minor road may be styled to have a line width of 30px.

To ensure consistent rendering between implementations, I would expect this would mean that a vector tile must have a defined conversion between "vector tile coordinates" and screen pixels (assuming it's being rendered at its native zoom level). I've seen some mention of 256px and/or 512px per tile, but I would expect this to be part of either the Vector Tile or Map Style specification. Changing a parameter like that would significantly affect the appearance of a map.

So: if I'm rendering a zoom-level-0 vector tile at exactly zoom level 0, how many pixels should the tile occupy on screen?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the expected render size is 512px based on [this blog article from Mapbox](https://blog.mapbox.com/512-map-tiles-cb5bfd6e72ba). It's not 100% critical what this render size is, but it's important to at least *know* it so that you can render exactly to the specification if desired.